# tabla pivot Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Contexto,

- tengo una tabla "web_orders"
- una tabla "products"
- y la tabla pivot es "web_order_products"

mi idea es:

> en base a un id de web order, que me muestre los productos de esa order.
> y que a cada producto que muestre, tenga La imagen del producto y su nombre

Un ejemplo de esto sería
con el id de order 1:

order 1, tiene 2 productos:

```
'sal de mesa', 'imagen sal de mesa' y 
'Sal de mar', 'imagen sal de mar'
```

**todo esto, en base a el id de order**

actualmente tengo esta parte de código

```
@foreach ($orders as $order)
@foreach ($order->products as $products)
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{Storage::url($products->privot->product->image)}}"></td>
        <td>{{$products->pivot->product->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$products->pivot->id}}</td>
        <td>${{number_format($products->pivot->price, 0,",",".")}}</td>
        <td>{{$products->pivot->quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

@endforeach
```

esta es la llamada del controlador

```
        $orders = WebOrder::get();
        return view('admin.webOrder.show', compact('orders'));
```

Relación Product con Web Order

```
//Relation with web order items 
public function webOrder(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\WebOrder');
}
```

Relación Web order Con product

```
//Relation with WebOrder
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'web_order_products', 'order_id', 'products_id')
        ->withPivot(['price', 'id', 'quantity']);
}
```

Tabla pivot

```
class WebOrderItem extends Pivot
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'products_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comentarios:

- Si vas a declarar un modelo para la tabla pivote, entonces te hacen falta algunos detalles [que aquí puedes leer mas a detalle](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)
- Lo siguiente es que puedes desde la consulta obtener de un modelo todas sus relaciones en una [carga ambiciosa](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- Puedes filtrar desde la misma consulta por la llave primaria del modelo **`WebOrder`** con el modelo **`findOrFail()`**

Lo anterior te devolvería:

- Un objeto con las propiedades y valores de la **`weborder`** (para acceder a los valores aqui no necesitas iterar)
- Una colección de todos los productos asociados a dicha web order (para leer todos los productos que tenga esta orden si necesitas iterarlos)

Tu consulta puede quedar así:

```
$listadoWebOrder = WebOrder::with('products')->findOrFail($id);
```

Donde **`$id`** será la llave primaria de la orden web que deseamos obtener junto con sus productos asociados.

Finalmente para filtrar sería algo como esto:

```
{{ $listadoWebOrder->propiedad1 }}
{{ $listadoWebOrder->propiedadN }}

@foreach($listadoWebOrder->products as $product)
    {{ $product->nombre }}
    <img src="{{ $product->imagen }}" alt="">
@endforeach
```

Para acceder a los demás atributos de la entidad intermedia, puedes seguir ocupando [**`pivot`**](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Como nota al margen, yo no veo necesidad de un modelo para la tabla pivote, al menos en este caso yo la quitaría y dejaría el resto como esta. (*pero claro esta es solo mi opinión*)

Comment: disculpa @BetaM me devuelve un error
Trying to get property 'products' of non-object 

`foreach ($orders as $order)
    foreach ($order->products as $product)
        <td><img src="{{ $product->image }}"></td>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
    endforeach
endforeach`


en la linea de comando

    `foreach ($order->products as $product)`

Comment: Hice un dd en el controlador para $orders y muestra [esto](https://prnt.sc/tre3ur)

Comment: como mostré en mi respuesta @DaglasRuizYañez no necesitas un doble foreach puesto que solo obtienes un registro de weborder, donde si necesitas un foreach es donde iteras los productos obtenidos de esa orden web

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste la vida <3 eres un amor de persona <3

Comment: @DaglasRuizYañez recuerda la mejor forma de agradecer es que si esta respuesta te ayudó entonces consideres marcarla como acepatada

Comment: Ya lo hice, muchas gracias, es caso de usar soft deletes? como sería?

Comment: Esa ya sería otra pregunta, te recomiendo trates algo si te atoras puedes publicar una duda con lo que lleves avanzado y te apoyamos